# Assign new vector to vector returned from function in C++

Tags: c++, vector, copy, return-value

I have a function in C++ that takes a vector, and constructs a vector of the same size with modified values, then returns it:

```
vector<double> sigmoid_from_vector(vector<double> v){
    int size = (v.size());//redundant but helps
    vector<double> sigvec(size);//Create empty vector to store sigmoid values
    for (int i = 1; i<=size; i++) {
      sigvec[i] = 1/(1+exp(-1*v[i]));
      //cout << "sig val calculated: " << sigvec[i] << endl;
    }
    return sigvec;
}
```

I cannot, for the life of me, use the returned vector. So for I have tried the following lines, that to my knowledge should work:

```
vector<double> testsig = sigmoid_from_vector(age_train);
vector<double> testsig = move(sigmoid_from_vector(age_train));
```

edit: I should go to bed. Thank you everyone

Comment: Why aren't you writing directly to `v`? Why create `sigvec`? `v` is already a local copy. Also vector index starts from `0` and not `1`. Moreover you have **undefined behavior** in your program since you're using `i<=size` instead of `i<size` and so will go out of bounds of the vector.

Comment: `i<=size` in the for loop is going to cause undefined behavior.  `container[size]` is the past the end element.

Comment: Instead of separate function you can use `std::for_each()` algorithm to achieve the same effect.

Comment: This has nothing to do with returning the vector. The logic in the function is broken, results in undefined behavior, memory corruption, and a crash. Array indexes in C and C++ start with 0, and not 1. Attempting any other logic always ends in tears.

Comment: I'm guessing you've had experience in other programming languages before picking up C++, and that you decided to just wing it instead of picking up a book that teaches you the basics.

Comment: You also should pass the vector by (const) reference, not by value.  Passing by value is a tell-tale sign you are either using another computer language (like Java, Python, JavaScript, C#) as a guide in learning C++ (which you should not do), or you skipped over in your reading material as to what passing by value actually does (makes a copy of the argument that's passed, incurring a possible performance penalty).

Comment: `sigvec[i] = 1/(1+exp(-1*v[i]));` If you changed that line to this: --> `sigvec.at(i) = 1/(1+exp(-1*v.at(i)));` -- you will quickly see that the `size` on the last iteration would wind up giving you a `std::out_of_range` exception.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with you given program.

**Problem 1**

Since you're using `i<=size` instead of `i<size` you'll go out of bound of the vector leadingto **undefined behavior**.

Additionally note that vector indexing starts from `0` and not `1` so you can replace `int i = 1` with `int i = 0`.

**Problem 2**

Moreover, there is no need to create a separate vector named `sigvec` as `v` is already a *local copy* of the passed vector.

Thus the total changes are as follows:

```
vector<double> sigmoid_from_vector(vector<double> v){
    
//---------------v--------------------->0 instead of 1
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
//-------------------^----------------->< instead of <=
      
        //other code here using v instead of sigvec
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have already made the changes. I only begin at 1 because these vectors I am using all have headers to be ignored in their first element.

Comment: @ConnerLee Ok, i see. Then its fine to start at `1` just as long as we use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Yeah, it was a stupid oversight. And thank you for reminding me to use local copies, I am quite rusty.

Comment: @ConnerLee Yeah mistakes/oversight happens sometimes. You're welcome :)